# using wait group to finish the goroutine

Tags: go

I' ve added to the following to stdout and stderr goroutine (go func() …)  to wait to get the `output` and the `error` is finished.
Now I want that the **outer function** will wait **until both routine will finished**.

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {

scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
go func() {
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
     }
}()

go func() {
scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        for scanerr.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
        }
}()

}
```

Now I’ve tried to add the wait group but it’s not working as im not sure how to pass the wait group instance, any idea ?

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {

scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)

var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup
waitgroup.Add(1)

go func() {
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
     }
}()

waitgroup.Wait()
waitgroup.Add(1)

go func() {
scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        for scanerr.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
        }
}()
waitgroup.Wait()

}
```

**update**

should it be like this ?

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {

scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)

var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup
waitgroup.Add(2)

go func() {
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
     }
}()

go func() {
scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        for scanerr.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
        }
}()
waitgroup.Wait()

}
```

Comment: I think all you need is `waitgroup.Done()` just below the `for` loops, no? Have you tried that?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks !so the code looks Ok? I need to add both like `add(1)` for `out` and `add(1)` for `error` ....or there is better way ?

Comment: I think you only need to call `Add(2)` once, and then have a single `Wait()` at the end if you want those two goroutines running concurrently, else why have those goroutines if you're waiting for both of them...

Comment: @mkopriva - can you please check my update, is this what you mean ?

Comment: you're missing the `Done` calls on the waitgroup. But I think you can probably even simplify it by removing the second goroutine, scanerr will run concurrently to scanout if scanout is in its own goroutine, no need to put scanerr in one as well. Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/KL4U5ceNI3o

Comment: Have you renamed the variable from `waitgroup` to `wg`, like in the example? If not either rename it, or use `waitgroup.Done()`.

Comment: Thanks, you can provide it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `WaitGroup` instance to the goroutine, since you're using a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) you can directly refer to a variable that was declared in the surrounding function.

Also you can omit the second goroutine, it's not really needed for your use-case.

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {
    scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    // exec scanout in its own goroutine
    go func() {
        for scanout.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // exec scanerr
    scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanerr.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
    }

    // wait for scanout
    wg.Wait()
}
```